# Meteor - Data saving issue

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this template:

```
<Template name="nuevoEjercicio">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="ejercicio" placeholder="Ejercicio?"/>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="repeticiones" placeholder="Repeticiones?" />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="peso" placeholder="Peso?" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</Template>
```

that I use to capture and save to the database.
Then on my .js file I am trying to get the data and save it:

```
  Template.nuevoEjercicio.events({
     'click .btn btn-success': function (event) {
      var ejercicio = event.target.ejercicio.value;
      var repeticiones = event.target.repeticiones.value;
      var peso = event.target.peso.value;


      ListaRutina.insert({
        rutina:"1",
        ejercicio:ejercicio,
        repeticiones:repeticiones,
        peso:peso,
        });

      // Clear form
      event.target.ejercicio.value = "";
      event.target.repeticiones.value = "";
      event.target.peso.value = "";

      // Prevent default form submit
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

as I understand, when I click on any object that has the btn btn-success style....but is not the case. For some obscure reason -for me- is not working.
Can you check it and give me some advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error? You should be getting one from `event.target.ejercicio.value`.

Comment: Not that I can see. You know just learning. On the javascript console I see:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/782/enojsmbs/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line.


But is present even I dont click on the button.

Comment: By the way, may someone knows: why on some examples I see:
 Template.TemplateName.events({
        'submit': function(event, template) {
on some others:
 Template.TemplateName.events({
        'submit': function(event) {
and on some others:
 Template.TemplateName.events({
        'submit': function() {

Comment: You can choose what parameters you accept and what you ignore. I'd always use `function(event, template) {...`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's an error in you selector. It's `'click .btn.btn-success'`, not `'click .btn btn-success'`.

Also you can't do that `event.target.ejercicio.value` thing. `event.target` is the element that was clicked. You'll have to do something like this:

```
'click .btn.btn-success': function (event, template) {
  var ejercicio = template.$('[name=ejercicio]').val()
  ...
```

Comment: ok...I don't understand why but made your sugested changes. And also added: window.alert("sometext"); to my JS file. But never fires. Is like it is not reacting to the click of the button.
This is so frustrating :(

Comment: I believe the event handler needs to be on `click .btn.btn-success` (no space in between the two classes). Assuming you only have one `.btn` class object in the DOM you can even potentially simplify to `click .btn`. To test selectors, just open up the js console in the page and type (for example): `$('.btn')` and see what comes back. That saves a lot of debugging time.

Comment: Well that a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks @MichelFloyd :)

Comment: np - that space gets me every time ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK
What after wasting hours and hours the solution is:
 1- on the html file give your input an id:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" **id="peso"** placeholder="Peso?" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn .btn-success" id="**guardar**" />
```

so now you want to save data on the input when the button is clicked:
2- You link the button with the funcion via the id

```
Template.TEMPLATENAMEONHTMLFILE.events({
     'click **#guardar**': function (event, template) {

      var ejercicio = template.$("**#peso**").val();
```

and get the value linking using the input id.